# C - Moving a node in a linked list

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, nodes

I'm dealing with a linked list, and I want to move a node in the list from one location to another without messing stuff up.

The struct of the linked list is:

```
 struct Frame
{
    char* name; // Name and path are just pointers to strings
    unsigned int duration;
    char* path;
};

typedef struct Frame frame_t;
```

And:

```
struct Link
{
    frame_t *frame;
    struct Link *next;
};
```

(That's how I was requested to do it, not my choice)

Now what I need is a function that receives the linked list and a string (a name of one of the nodes) and an integer, and then moves the node with that name to that position (the integer received) the first position being 1, not 0 (that's what was requested)

So for example:
If the list contains the nodes: [pic1, pic2, pic3, pi4]
And the user requested to move "pic1" to pos 3, then the new list would be:
[pic2, pic3, pic1, pic4] (and pic2 would be the new head)

I've tried some version but they always only 80% worked (either cutting off the list or not moving to the correct location). Any ideas?

Heres the function I've tried:

```
 void changePos(link_t** anchor_link, char* name1, int pos)
{
    link_t* currLink = *anchor_link;
    link_t* temp = NULL;
    link_t* temp2 = NULL;
    int i;

    if (strcmp(name1, currLink->frame->name) == 0 && currLink->next)
    {
        *anchor_link = (*anchor_link)->next;
        temp = currLink;
    }
    else
    {
        while (strcmp(name1, currLink->next->frame->name) != 0 && currLink->next)
        {
            currLink = currLink->next;
        }

        temp = currLink->next;
    }

    currLink = *anchor_link;

    for (i = 1; i < pos - 1; i++) // Go up until the node before the pos (meaning if pos is 4 then node 3)
    {
            currLink = currLink->next;
    }

    // Now we insert the temp node at the pos

    temp2 = currLink->next->next;
    currLink->next->next = temp;
    temp->next = temp2;
}
```

Comment: frame_t is not defined. did you forget a typedef of some sort?

Comment: show us what you've tried and where the problems are with your solution.

Comment: You will need to show the code so we can help you fix it (an MCVE ([MCVE])) — show us your best effort.  That's a lot of pointers in the `struct Link`.  It isn't clear what a `frame_t` is, except it is not a `struct Frame` unless you've missed a crucial `typedef` line.  To move nodes in a single-linked list, you need to know the node before the one to be moved (and hence the one to be moved), and you need to know the one it is to be moved after.  You have to worry about degenerate cases, and pointers that identify the head (and tail?) of the list.

Comment: @SpacePotato  What will be if the position is set to 0?

Comment: @noob Yes I used typedef, edited the code.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Added the function

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's sort  of what I tried to do, I edited the post and added my code for you to check

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Then the function will tell the user that it is not an option.

Comment: @SpacePotato thanks for updating your question, but what we need is an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), please take 5 minutes and [read that](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Using positions to identify nodes in lists is unusual.  What does the position mean?  Is it that in the resulting list, the moved node must be in the numbered position?  It would be more usual (natural?) to identify the node that the moved node should be moved before, or after.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The position is where the moved node shall be in the resulting list, after being moved. I know it is unusual, but this is how I was asked to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I came up with — the `changePos()` function and the test code I created to be moderately confident it is correct.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Frame
{
    char *name;
    unsigned int duration;    // Effectively unused
//  char *path;               // Actually unused
};

typedef struct Frame Frame;

struct Link
{
    Frame *frame;
    struct Link *next;
};

typedef struct Link Link;

static void print_list(Link *root);

static void changePos(Link **anchor_link, const char *name, int pos)
{
    assert(anchor_link != 0 && name != 0 && pos >= 0);
    Link *root = *anchor_link;
    Link *link = root;
    Link *prev = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while (link != 0 && strcmp(link->frame->name, name) != 0)
    {
        prev = link;
        link = link->next;
        count++;
    }
    if (link == 0)      // Name not found - no swap!
        return;
    if (count == pos)   // Already in target position - no swap
        return;
    if (count == 0)     // Moving first item; update root
    {
        assert(link == root);
        *anchor_link = root->next;
        root = *anchor_link;
    }
    else
    {
        assert(prev != 0);
        prev->next = link->next;
    }
    // link is detached; now where does it go?
    if (pos == 0)       // Move to start; update root
    {
        link->next = root;
        *anchor_link = link;
        return;
    }
    Link *node = root;
    for (int i = 0; i < pos - 1 && node->next != 0; i++)
        node = node->next;
    link->next = node->next;
    node->next = link;
}

static void print_list(Link *root)
{
    const char *pad = "";
    while (root != 0)
    {
        printf("%s[%s]", pad, root->frame->name);
        root = root->next;
        pad = "->";
    }
}

static void free_frame(Frame *frame)
{
    if (frame != 0)
    {
        free(frame->name);
        free(frame);
    }
}

static void free_link(Link *link)
{
    while (link != 0)
    {
        Link *next = link->next;
        free_frame(link->frame);
        free(link);
        link = next;
    }
}

static Frame *make_frame(const char *name, unsigned int number)
{
    Frame *frame = malloc(sizeof(*frame));
    if (frame != 0)
    {
        frame->name = strdup(name);
        frame->duration = number;
    }
    return frame;
}

static Link *make_link(const char *name, unsigned int number)
{
    Link *link = malloc(sizeof(*link));
    if (link != 0)
    {
        link->frame = make_frame(name, number);
        link->next = 0;
    }
    return link;
}

static Link *make_list(int num, Frame *frames)
{
    Link *head = 0;
    Link *tail = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < num; k++)
    {
        Link *link = make_link(frames[k].name, frames[k].duration);
        assert(link != 0 && link->frame != 0);  // Lazy!
        if (head == 0)
            head = link;
        if (tail != 0)
            tail->next = link;
        tail = link;
    }
    return head;
}

int main(void)
{
    Frame frames[] =
    {
        { "pic0", 0 },
        { "pic1", 1 },
        { "pic2", 2 },
        { "pic3", 3 },
        { "pic4", 4 },      // Never in the list, but searched for
    };
    enum { NUM_FRAMES = sizeof(frames) / sizeof(frames[0]) };

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_FRAMES; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_FRAMES; j++)
        {
            Link *head = make_list(NUM_FRAMES - 1, frames);
            print_list(head);
            printf(" == %s to %u == ", frames[i].name, j);
            changePos(&head, frames[i].name, j);
            print_list(head);
            putchar('\n');
            free_link(head);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I suspect that the code in `changePos()` can be streamlined a bit still, but I haven't spotted how yet.  It's an ugly interface with the numeric positions and a list — it would be more natural to use another name to identify where the node should be moved to.  With numeric positions, you're tempted to use an array instead of a list.

Sample output:

```
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic0 to 0 == [pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3]
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic0 to 1 == [pic1]->[pic0]->[pic2]->[pic3]
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic0 to 2 == [pic1]->[pic2]->[pic0]->[pic3]
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic0 to 3 == [pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3]->[pic0]
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic0 to 4 == [pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3]->[pic0]
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic1 to 0 == [pic1]->[pic0]->[pic2]->[pic3]
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic1 to 1 == [pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3]
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic1 to 2 == [pic0]->[pic2]->[pic1]->[pic3]
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic1 to 3 == [pic0]->[pic2]->[pic3]->[pic1]
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic1 to 4 == [pic0]->[pic2]->[pic3]->[pic1]
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic2 to 0 == [pic2]->[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic3]
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic2 to 1 == [pic0]->[pic2]->[pic1]->[pic3]
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic2 to 2 == [pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3]
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic2 to 3 == [pic0]->[pic1]->[pic3]->[pic2]
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic2 to 4 == [pic0]->[pic1]->[pic3]->[pic2]
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic3 to 0 == [pic3]->[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic3 to 1 == [pic0]->[pic3]->[pic1]->[pic2]
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic3 to 2 == [pic0]->[pic1]->[pic3]->[pic2]
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic3 to 3 == [pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3]
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic3 to 4 == [pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3]
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic4 to 0 == [pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3]
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic4 to 1 == [pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3]
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic4 to 2 == [pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3]
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic4 to 3 == [pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3]
[pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3] == pic4 to 4 == [pic0]->[pic1]->[pic2]->[pic3]
```

The LHS of the output is the list before — always the same, in the sequence pic0 to pic3.  The RHS of the output is the list after invoking `changePos`.  For positions *n = 0..3*, you can see, 'picn' migrating from position 0 to position 3 in turn.  The name `pic4` is never inserted into the list, so nothing changes when it is sought.  Also, when you try to move any of the names to a position that doesn't exist, it is moved to the last position in the list.  Positions less than 0 are asserted invalid.

The code has casual error checking.  It asserts its way out of memory allocation problems, and some other problems too (such as positions less than 0).

I made the harness run cleanly with a dummy do-nothing version of `changePos()` before writing anything of value in `changePos()`.

The code compiles and runs cleanly on Mac OS X 10.11.5 with GCC 6.1.0 and Valgrind 3.12.0.SVN, using my habitual compiler warning options:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     -Wold-style-definition -Werror so.3807-9550.c -o so.3807-9550
$
```

Comment: Your version worked out perfectly, two things though.
1. I didn't know what assert is, but seems pretty comfortable to use.
2. You used index 0, and had cases where index 3 and 4 had the same result if 4 was the last one. I changed it to what I needed ( being that 1 is the first index / position and if there are 4 nodes then 4 is the last) and it worked out very well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your general approach is fine: locate the target node, remove it from the list, then reinsert it at the specified position.  You have several problems with your code, however.

First, consider the condition of this `while()` loop:

> ```
>     while (strcmp(name1, currLink->next->frame->name) != 0 && currLink->next)
> ```

If you are uncertain whether `currLink->next` is `NULL` (and you should be) then you must perform the null check *before* dereferencing it, which you do in the expression `currLink->next->frame->name`.  As it is, your code exhibits undefined behavior if it reaches the end of the list without finding the specified name.

Second, your variable naming leaves a bit to be desired.  What's `temp`?  What's `temp2`?  What does the `1` in `name1` signify, given that there is no `name2` in sight?  Naming your variables in a way that clearly conveys their purpose helps in writing and analyzing code.  What's wrong with "target_node", for example?

Third, your insertion code is wrong:

> ```
> temp2 = currLink->next->next;
> currLink->next->next = temp;
> temp->next = temp2;
> ```

You intend to insert `*temp` between `*currLink` and `*currLink->next`, but in fact you put it *after* `*currLink->next` and then close a two-element loop.  Also, I suspect use of `temp2` is just muddling this code.  I would write this:

```
temp->next = currLink->next->next;
currLink->next = temp;
```

Fourth, you have no provision for inserting at position 1 in your list.  The way you're doing it requires a special case for that.